# rails render json nested two levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I expand associations more than one level deep? Right now I can expand `reviews` but am not sure how to also expand `the patient_profile_id`?

```
class Review
   belongs_to :patient_profile
end

render json: doctors.to_json(
      :include => {:reviews => {:include => :patient_profile_id }}
)
```

Comment: Hey, did my answer work for you?

Comment: @TheChamp going to give it a try tomorrow, i'll let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd highly suggest you check out the [jbuilder gem](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder). There's a [great railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder) that explains it's usage.

Basically, you will have to add a jbuilder file into your views, that gives you allot more control over your json.

For your specific use case you'd use something like this:

**doctors/index.json.jbuilder**

```
json.doctors @doctors do |json, doctor|
  json.(doctor, :id, :name)

  json.reviews doctor.reviews do |json, review|
    json.(review, :id, :rating, :patient_profile_id)

    json.patient_profile review.patient_profile do |json, profile|
      json.(profile, :id, :name, ... ) # attributes of the profile
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to answer my question. you're still returning the patient_profile_id instead of the actually profile

Comment: It's easy to deepen the nesting. I updated my answer to get you the real profile.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use something like this:

```
render json: doctors.to_json(
      :include => {:reviews => {:include => :patient_profile  }}
)
```

[Here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) you can find detail information how to serialize nested objects.

Answer (score -1):

Check for overriding as_json method